# Who is this shadowy figure?

Tags: mortal-kombat-3

This is not a game identification game, but instead a person identification.

---

In Mortal Kombat 3 (or MK2, I don't remember right) after fighting lots of bosses, I remember you fight with this guy. He was extremely powerful and fast, and (I think) I never beat him.

Here is a picture I found searching for this mysterious shadowy figure:

[image: The Black Guy]

---

## Information:

- **Platform**: Played in a [PlayStation 1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_(console));
- **Genre**: Fighting game;
- **Year**: Mortal Kombat (if this guy its from MK3, the year is 1995, if this guy be from MK2, the year is 1993) is a little old, but I played last year.
- **Perspective**: Its a 2D game;

---

So who is this shadowy figure? What his name, what is the plot around him, and what games he appeared?

Comment: I feel like "shadowy figure" might be a better descriptor here...

Comment: I feel like there's room for a [Lion King meme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDBfA.jpg) here too...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This character appears to be [Noob Saibot](http://mortalkombat.wikia.com/wiki/Noob_Saibot)

> [image]
>
> Noob Saibot, once known as Bi-Han (璧漢 or 避寒)[1](http://mortalkombat.wikia.com/wiki/Noob_Saibot) and the original Sub-Zero, was a Lin Kuei assassin turned wraith from the Mortal Kombat fighting games series. He is one of the few original characters, debuting in the original Mortal Kombat arcade game as Sub-Zero, older brother of the current, younger Sub-Zero. He first appeared as Noob Saibot as a secret character in Mortal Kombat II, first becoming playable in Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3, and was once again a secret character in Mortal Kombat 4. In one form or another, Noob Saibot has appeared in every generation of Mortal Kombat games as a playable character.

Comment: Also fun fact too Noob Saibot is that named after two of the founding members of the Mortal Kombat team Ed Boon and John Tobias.